# Soap based web services using ruby on rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to write soap based web services using ruby on rails framework. If yes, can someone please point to a learning resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write SOAP web services using Rails, However Rails is moving in favour of a REST web service approach. So my personal opinion is if you are starting a brand new Rails app with SOAP web services, consider some other programming language like JAVA, because that has more tools to easily create SOAP web services.

But nowadays all the webservices going towards REST, because of the simplicity it has. Almost all major sites has a REST API.

Furthermore if you are still planning to go ahead with Rails, [savon](http://savonrb.com/) is an interesting gem that you should probably look at.